# How to display flutter table_calendar in list form?

Tags: flutter

I want to customise the flutter table_calendar package such that it displays all the months in a year in a single page in the form of a scrollable list.

Thanks in advance.

[This is the expected output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRS9S.png)

Comment: Please add expected result screenshot if possible

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your TableCalendar in ListItem of ListView, set headerVisible: false for TableCalendar, create your own header (Month title) in ListItem, give CalendarController to Table Calendar, controller setFocusedDay to each month.